# Trying to display one image on top of another SDL2 no errors but second image wont display

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm doing a test with a super simple multiple choice game, but I cant put an image on top of my background. The file names are correct, and my background is displayed first.

My code is giving me no errors and the program is running, just with only the background displaying.  I have no idea what the issue is.

```
void Display(SDL_Surface*& windowsurface, SDL_Surface*& background, SDL_Surface*& image, SDL_Window*& window, SDL_Rect& scaleRect, int &slide){
    if(slide == 2){
        image == SDL_LoadBMP("image-3.bmp");
    }
    else if(slide == 3){
        image == SDL_LoadBMP("image-2.bmp");
    }
    else if(slide == 4){
        image == SDL_LoadBMP("image-3.bmp");
    }
    if(slide < 5){
        background = SDL_LoadBMP("background-1.bmp");
    }
    else if(slide == 5 || slide == 8 || slide == 11){
        background = SDL_LoadBMP("background-2.bmp");
    }
    else if(slide == 6 || slide == 9 || slide == 12){
        background = SDL_LoadBMP("background-3.bmp");
    }
    else if(slide == 7 || slide == 10 || slide == 13){
        background = SDL_LoadBMP("background-4.bmp");
    }
SDL_BlitSurface(background, NULL, windowsurface, NULL);
SDL_BlitScaled(image, NULL, windowsurface, &scaleRect);
SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

}
```

Comment: draw the background first. By drawing it second you are drawing it on top. Your other image is probably there but covered up.

Comment: Look closely at `image == SDL_LoadBMP("image-3.bmp");`. Do you have warnings enabled?

Comment: Originally I displayed the image second however when it didn't display I displayed the image first, I must have forgotten to switch it back. Sorry:)

Comment: `image == SDL_LoadBMP("image-2.bmp")` is an expression which tests where `image` is equal to the output of `SDL_LoadBMP`. You probably meant to use a single `=` for assignment

Comment: but thank you black cat, that was the issue, I never thought it would be such a stupid one.

Answer (score 0):

I used == as an operator when loading the image to image 1, that doesn't actually set it to image 1.
what I should have done:

```
image = loadBMP("image-1.bmp");
```

instead of

```
image == loadBMP("image-1.bmp);
```